# How to use java 8 (LAMBDA) to check the collection if all the periods object are continuous periods

Tags: java, lambda, collections

...

```
public class DateLimiter {
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
 }

List<DateLimiter> period = new ArrayList<>();
period.add(1/1/2020, 31/1/2020);
period.add(1/2/2020, 29/2/2020);
period.add(1/3/2020, 1/5/2020);

period.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o2.getStartDate()));
```

...

How to use java 8 (LAMBDA)  to check the collection if all the periods object are  continuous periods
for example endDate+1 "day" should be equals to the next period startDate

Comment: Why do you want a lambda/stream? A plain loop would work, which is how I’d code it. You could do it with a stream reduce, but that would be contrived and not as efficient either.

Comment: To get the difference between two `LocalDate`s you can use the method `between` from the `Period` class. Look examples here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-period-duration

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a number of things incorrectly or not at all.

1. Trying to add a non-string to an `ArrayList` that only takes `DateLimiter` objects.
2. Trying to add two elements to an `ArrayList` with `add`.
3. Not creating instances of `DateLimiter`.

You should also be using `LocalDate` and not `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you must use `java.util.Date` and the list is sorted, you can use the function below.

```java
public boolean isCorrect(ArrayList<DateLimiter> list) {
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Date prevEndDate = list.get(i - 1).getEndDate();
        Date currStartDate = list.get(i).getStartDate();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(prevEndDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        if (cal.getTime().equals(currStartDate)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```